# Getting faceboom time post - timezone

Tags: php, facebook, timezone

I would like to get a posts from my FB group but I have a problem with timezone. For example, one post was sent at 22:01 (in Poland). When I try to get this time by PHP, I get: **2016-04-03T20:01:00+0000** 
How to get this time post as timezone - Europe/Warsaw (that should be 22:01).

Now I get this time by that way:

```
strtotime($value['created_time'])
```

And this return: 20:01. How to solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change timezone:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2016-04-03T20:01:00+0000');
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Warsaw'));
echo $dt->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/547214)</kbd>